# Strange hang "ls -l" or "dir -l" not working

Tags: linux, debian, ls, command

I have a strange behaviour on a Debian server.

Context : `Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u5 (2015-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

User : `root`

Commands `ls`, `ls -a`, `ls -1` or `dir` work perfectly.
But these command **`ls -l`**, **`dir -l`** only on the `/` directory theses tow commands hang the terminal.

Comment: run it in `strace` to see where, exactly, it hangs.

Comment: Thanks you !
`.etc.....
getxattr("lib", "system.posix_acl_access", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
getxattr("lib", "system.posix_acl_default", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
lstat("DB_ARCHIVES", `
It's probably the size or rule issues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls`/`ls -a`... just read the content of the current directory, it doesn't do anything with the files.

`ls -l` or `ls -F` or `ls --color` need to get meta-data information from the listed files themselves (permission, type, ownership, modification time...). So in addition to the `getdents()` system call to read the directory's content, it needs to do a `lstat()` for each file listed in there, and also a `readlink()` for symlinks (and a `stat()` as well for symlinks with some `ls` implementations with `-F` or `--color`).

For the `+` or `@` and other *optional alternate access method flags* sometimes found after the permissions, it may need to do some extra system calls (like `getxattr()` on Linux to retrieve ACLs).

With `ls -l`, it also needs to query the user database to translate uid and gid to user name and group name.

So, while for a simple `ls`, we just need to open one file (the current working directory) and read its content, it's easy to see that there's a lot more scope for things failing with `-l`/`-F`/`--color`...:

- the `lstat()` may fail or hang if the file is a mount point on a file system that is unavailable.
- the `stat()` on a symlink may fail if the target of the symlink is on a fs that is unavailable.
- the query to the user database may fail or hang (like in deployments using network (LDAP/NIS+) user databases.

Answer (score 0):

One of folders in my `/` directory is an volume folder, mounted from another machine, this one was shutdown. The mounted directory it was unattainable.

Comment: Could you clarify that, please? What kind of "volume"? From your problem description, it sounds like a network mountpoint of some sort…

Comment: As the remote volume is impossible to achieve, ask the stats by the command ls -l` or `dir -l` are missing and hang the terminal.